# What name was Yeshua baptized in?

Tags: baptism, john-the-baptist, life-of-jesus

What name was Yeshua baptized in by John the Baptist.  Could it be The God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob?

Comment: Are you sure that John's baptism was **in the name of** anyone?

Answer (score 3):

John's was a baptism of repentance. It was a cleaning of the body, according to the Law that commanded those who were unclean to "wash with water".

This is not the same baptism as that in Christ since the Apostles baptized in the name of Christ those who had already received John's baptism in Acts 19.

Answer (score 0):

It is never entirely clear. When Jesus asks the religious leaders where baptism came from they could not answer. John refused to baptize religious leaders until they showed works befitting it. So this was not a mainstream religious concept. When asked point blank about baptism, John answered that it was to reveal the one who would baptize with Holy Spirit. Baptism in the name of the Father, Son and Holy Spirit are only mentioned in Matthew. Peter only baptized in the name of Jesus. It seems that later when it was discovered new proselytes had only the baptism of John, they had to be re baptized.